# MySQL. ENUM в 30+ значений или отдельная таблица

Tags: mysql, база-данных, enum

Есть наименования товаров: сумки, кошельки, перчатки и т.д. БД MySQL.

Вопрос не как сделать, а как сделать правильно. От БД очень далек.

Вариант первый: сделать таблицу товара в ней id на наименование товара в другой таблице.
Вариант второй: сделать ENUM с этими наименованиями.

Если возможно, развернутый ответ по каждому варианту. Сделать, я как-нибудь сделаю и сам. Вопрос задаю в целях саморазвития.

Comment: Правильно - таблица.

Answer (score 1):

Так как это товары, то завтра нужно будет что-то новое добавить, что-то отредактировать, добавить произвольную сортировку или же еще что-то, то для этого лучше отдельная таблица.
Поле ENUM для этих целей не подойдет, у неё есть ограничения, и завтра у вас возникнут проблемы